# How can I get a mobile phone’s virtual keyboard height using javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile

**Problem:**

I want to put a fixed element just above the mobile phone’s virtual keyboard like in the picture below. I want the `div` to be fixed above the virtual keyboard. Also, I am using react. Is there a way of fixing this using the framework?

[***Refer to this picture***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBp93.jpg)

**My temporary solution:**

I hardcoded the `bottom position` of the `div` so it sits above the virtual keyboard. However, I want it to be flexible and responsive to all different mobile devices. I tried searching for answers on the internet but none of them worked for me.

```
.toolbar {
position: absolute;
bottom: 270px;
}
```

Are there any possible solutions to help adjust this? Any help would be great and I’d really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if the parent element has a height of 100%

You can see this [exemple](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-water-huf90)

Comment: Tried this before, still doesn’t work. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to use the `fixed` position and add a `bottom: 0` value  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position like so

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0
```

So that your element is fixed to the bottom of the viewport

Comment: I tried position fixed, still doesent work for me. Thank you for answering.